# Access one function from every class

Tags: java, function, class, md5

I would like to know the easier way to access a function from any file that I want

For example i got this function :

```
public String MD5(String md5) {
   try {
        java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] array = md.digest(md5.getBytes());
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
          sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
       }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

I want this function to be called from every files .java that I got, how to do that?

Comment: Why would you want that? How do you want to call it? What is it meant to do?

Comment: It's meant to crypt any string that I want , for example I am in the loginPage class (which have to make a people log in) and I want to access this function within the loginPage class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you declare the function in a public class, you can access it anywhere you want. if that function was in `Utils.java`,

```
public class Utils {
  public static String MD5(...) { ... };
}
```

from any other class, you could access it like,

```
String s = Utils.MD5(...);
```

Comment: `MD5()` method is not **static**.

Answer (score 1):

IF this function only relies on the input provided and returns back the same output for the same input irrespective of the state of the program, then you should make it **static** :

```
 public static String MD5(String md5) {
    // do something
 }
```

Then this function can be accessed form any class as follows :

```
  String md5Val = Utils.MD5("my string");
```

Comment: @Jeffrey Blattman I guess I had pasted the static answer first and then you modified your function to be static. The only thing I had missed out was the usage of the function, which I added later.